# How to reset click counter in VueJs + TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I created a Counter component that should display the total of button clicks and reset after a given X mins.

in `Counter.vue` I have :

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';

@Component
export default class Counter extends Vue {
  valueNumber: number = 0;

  get formattedNumber() {
    return `Your total number is: ${this.valueNumber}`;
  }
</script>
```

My `<template>` is :

```
<div>
    <fieldset>
      <legend><p>You have clicked{{ this.formattedNumber }} times!</p></legend>
        <button @click="valueNumber">Click Here</button>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</template>
```

But it is not working and I have yet to figure out how to reset it, any advice or guidance would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Learn javascript. This isn't really a vue issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) if you want to reset the counter value after every X minutes or if you just want to reset it only once then you can use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) method.

**Live Demo** (I am resetting the counter in mounted hook but you can make it happen as per your requirement) **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    valueNumber: 0
  },
  computed: {
    formattedNumber() {
      return `button : ${this.valueNumber}`;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.valueNumber = 0
    }, 5000);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <fieldset>
      <legend><p>You have clicked {{ formattedNumber }} times!</p></legend>
        <button @click="valueNumber += 1">Click Here</button>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout`

```js
const runAfter = 1000 * 60 * 10 // 10 minutes in miliseconds
setTimeout(() => {
 // set counter here 
}, runAfter)
```